# How to re-enable Google mail?

Tags: 8.1, email, lumia

In attempt to downgrade my phone to be a bit more dumb during vacation, I disabled synchronisation on my Google account inside the email settings.

I was a bit surprised when the email tile disappeared off the start screen but figured I'd work out what to do later.

Later is now, and I discover that in my email settings, the Google account is there, but grayed out. It is impossible to select or delete, and I can't re-add because it says "already exists".

I've searched around a bit and found others with the same or similar problems, and I've tried the soft-resets-in-airplane-mode with no success.

So, before doing the full hard reset, I wondered if anyone might have a less drastic solution?

Failing that, what are the chances that restoring apps and settings after the hard reset will also restore this faulty configuration?

Comment: Just for the record, I ended up doing a hard reset.

Comment: You were supposed to do a SOFT RESET. That could've solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing and able to do some registry hacking, I could tell you how to find the settings for email accounts, though you'll need a pretty privileged registry editor to mess with them.

Otherwise, your best bet short of a hard-reset is probably to [turn on IMAP access for your Gmail account](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en), and then set it up as an IMAP account on the phone. Unfortunately, this will only give you email sync, no contacts or calendar data.

It's unlikely that the screwed-up state would persist across a hard-reset, but it's unlikely that it would happen in the first place, so I don't have a good answer.

Comment: I'll have a go at the registry...